# Stages vs. Order in numerical analysis for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, runge-kutta-methods

I'm reading [this](http://62.182.86.140/main/1539000/43a7a457b95e0443c75d23dc1b46fee7/J.%20C.%20Butcher%20-%20Numerical%20Methods%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20Equations-Wiley%20%282016%29.pdf) interesting book by Butcher.

I do not understand what are the definitions of **stages** and **orders** of numerical methods.

I think that these 2 terms are somewhat overloaded.

Which page for their definitions should I consult in the book to grasp them both?

**EDIT:**

I think that at least **order** has 2 different meaning: one of them being exact for polynomials of order at most $p$ and the other that the error
converges as fast as $\cal{O}(h^{p+1})$.

**EDIT Stages and orders**
I have located **stages and orders** in the book but I'm still
unaware what do the notions mean.

[image]

[image]

**ORDER**

[image]

Comment: @Moo Is it the case that order$\geq$stage or on the contrary stage$\geq$order ? Where can I find this fact in the book cited ?

Comment: Please give your interpretations for relevant passages of the book also for "stage". Make a careful distinction of what applies to Runge-Kutta methods and what to linear multi-step methods.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I have located some initial occurrences of an **order** and a **stage**, but I'm still unaware what do they technically mean. Please see the 3 snippets in my OQ. Perhaps you can have a look at the link from my OQ and give me the definition pages ? **Both** for Rugne-Kutta and linear multistep methods.

Comment: If you have something that looks like a polynomial or power series, like the local (unit-step) or global error expansions, then order is the lowest occurring power. In RK methods, stages correspond to the rows of the $A$ matrix, for explicit methods it is also the number of function evaluations in a step.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Is it really the **lowest** term in the polynomial ? In $x+x^2+\cal{O}(x^3)$ is the order 3 is that correct ? It is on the cotrary the **highest**. What moreover about my Q. from the first comment which case is it order$\geq$stage or stage$\geq$order ? Where can I locate this inequality in the book ? Thank you.

Comment: In such a formula, $x+x^2$ would be either the true value or the approximation, from a Picard iteration perhaps. The error would start with a cubic term. Or sometimes the split is for $x$ being the true value, and of the second order error the leading therm $x^2$ is given explicitly. // You can not locate this inequality because it is not true in general. For explicit RK you get stages $\ge$ order. A possibility is when starting to explain variable-step methods after RK4.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Please how does look the DE method for this simplest possible Butcher table:  \begin{bmatrix}
   0  & 0 \\
   0  & 1 \\
  \end{bmatrix} on the page 98 the bottom part ?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Just to be sure that I understand Butcher Tables, also for this one? \begin{bmatrix}
   0  & 0 & 0\\
   1 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3}\\1 & \frac{1}{4} &\frac{3}{4}\\
  \end{bmatrix} ?

Comment: @LutzLehmann This comment is just to make me sure that I interpret the Butcher's tables properly.

Comment: The first is explicit Euler, the second is an implicit method that has only order 1. The numbers are related to what is commonly called the 2nd order Heun-Ralston method, but that has the table \begin{array}{c|cc}0&\\\frac23&\frac23&\\\hline1&\frac14&\frac34\end{array}

Comment: @LutzLehmann How do you know that the second is implicit **and** has order only $1$ ?

Comment: Because $A$ is not purely sub-diagonal, the $\frac23$ is on the diagonal.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Could you please have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4691483/the-taylors-expansions) or you have already come across it ?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Could you please have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695021/explicit-runge-kutta-method-for-solving-ode) ?