# Explicit Runge-Kutta method for solving ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I would like to understand in some detail why [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) Runge-Kutta method is explicit if and only if $c_1=0$.
Why in this case the r.h.s. doesn't contain $y_{n+1}$ ?

**EDIT** $c_1=0$

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I would also like to know if this implicit Euler method

$$\begin{array}{c|c}1&1\\\hline&1\end{array}$$
is implicit in $k_1$ or also in $y_{n+1}$.

In other words, is it possible to obtain **all these 4 possibilities**?

Like being $(i)$ implicit for $k_1$ and explicit for $y_1$,

$(ii)$ implicit for $k_1$ and implicit for $y_1$,

$(iii)$ explicit for $k_1$ and explicit for $y_1$,

$(iv)$ explicit for $k_1$ and implicit for $y_1$

all of this for some suitable $s\geq 1$ stage method or perhaps
with other index $i$ than $i=1$ ?

In other words do we/can we distinguish already in the definition **in which variable**
namely whether $k_i$ or $y_i$
is the method implicit and in which it is explicit ?

Still, in your formula in the comment $y_{n+1}=y_n+hk_1$ the r.h.s. doesn't contain
$y_{n+1}$.

Comment: Where on that page do you see a $c_0$? Write down the stage equation if $c_1\ne 0$, or explore deeper what it means that $A$ is sub-diagonal. You might also want to deeper explain how you determine that a method is implicit.

Comment: @LutzLehmann For me $c_0$ is in the leftmost column $1$st row. I.e. the top left  element. I do not know that notion of a **sub-diagonal** matrix $A$, could you please explain what does that mean ? I understand that  a method is implicit if the r.h.s. contains $y_{n+1}$. Please see also my edit to understand wehre is $0=c_0$ in the Butcher's table.

Comment: If you take the other elements of the first column into account, its first entry is $c_1$. A sub-diagonal matrix is zero o the diagonal and above.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I see it was a typo that I have mentioned $c_0$ instead of $c_1$. I'm unable to write down the equation of this the most elementary $2$-element Butcher's table $0|{}_1$. This is the important part of my question.

Comment: You mean the tableau $\begin{array}{c|c}0&\\\hline&1\end{array}$ of the explicit Euler method $k_1=f(x_n,y_n)$, $y_{n+1}=y_n+hk_1$? Note that empty spaces in the $A$ region stand for entries zero.

Comment: Yes this one explicit Euler, but also this one implicit Euler: $1|1_1$. Could you please give me analogous equation for that implicit ? Is that $y_{n+1}=y_n+hf(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ ? I'm also unable write your nice display of the Butcher's table.

Comment: With a right-click on a formula you can open a TeX source view for it. And yes, that is correct for implicit Euler. In the stages formulation you get $k_1=f(x_n+h,y_n+hk_1)$, which is implicit for $k_1$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Please why is on the l.h.s. $k_1$ and not $y_{n+1}$ ? What are the two complete equations involving both $k_1$ and $y_{n+1}$ for this table $$\begin{array}{c|c}1&1\\\hline&1\end{array}$$ ?

Comment: @LutzLehmann $k_1$ involves only $y_n$ and not $y_{n+1}$.

Comment: As before, $y_{n+1}=y_n+hk_1$. The Euler methods are too simple, the stage formulation makes begins to make sense only for methods with more stages.

Comment: Also, please update the main question text with the essence of your comments so that it makes sense for me to combine my answering comments into a main answer text.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I have just updated my OQ to pose a question which I'm currently interested in. For your formula $y_{n+1}=y_n+hk_1$ please see the last line of the **EDIT**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In explicit one-step or Runge-Kutta methods, at the start of each step none of the slopes inside the step are known. Thus the first stage is always $k_1=f(x_n,y_n)$, that is, $c_1=0$. There is no information to reach inside the step interval.

The Euler methods are at an intersection of ideas that become distinct for higher-order methods, a conceptional twilight, undifferentiated embryonic forms. They are Runge-Kutta, but also linear multi-step. Their direct formulation à la multi-step is more intuitive than the separation of stages and composition that is usually done in the Runge-Kutta methods.

In general, when the explicit or implicit computation of $k_1, ..., k_s$ is finished, then the composition $y_{n+1}=y_n+h(b_1k_1+...+b_sk_s)$ is an explicit formula.

However, as already mentioned, in the one-stage methods $\begin{array}{c|c}\theta&\theta\\\hline &1\end{array}$ the composition is a direct linear relation between $k_1$ and $y_{n+1}$, one can be eliminated against the other. In this sense if $k_1$ is implicit, then so is $y_{n+1}$ and v.v. and inverse.

Comment: Dear Lutz, could you please have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4698480/a-taylor-expansion-at-x-n) ?